# How to read data from Access database and Excel together using same OleDbConnection in VB .Net

Tags: excel, oledbconnection

I have a table in Access database and another table in Excel with a unique column called `[Number]`.
I would like to know how to connect to both these source together using a single **OleDbConnection** so that I can execute a query something like this in  VB .Net.

```
SELECT [Sheet1$].[Number], [Sheet1$].[Vendor],[Sheet1$].[Details], ,TableinAccess.[Datefield], TableinAccess.[Agreement],TableinAccess.Comments 
FROM  ([Sheet1$] LEFT OUTER JOIN TableinAccess ON [Sheet1$].[Number] = TableinAccess.[Number])
```

Idea is to fill the Gridview with data from both source.

Eg:

Excel have below table(Sheet1),

Number    Vendor    Details
1            vend1            xxx
2            vend2                xxx
3            vend3                xxx

Access have below table(TableinAccess),
Number    Datefield    Agreement    Comments
1            vend1                    xxx            something
2            vend2                    xxx                  something

### I have to fill my Gridview like this,

Number    Vendor    Details        Datefield        Agreement     Comments
1            vend1                xxx                  vend1                    xxx                  something
2            vend2                xxx                  vend2                    xxx                  something
3            vend3                xxx                   null                        null                     null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you describe because the two data sources are completely isolated from each other.

An OLEDB connection can only connect to a single "thing" (DB Server, file, etc.) at a time.

To do a JOIN, you would need to copy the Excel data to a temporary table in Access or link to it from Access, and then do the join in Access.

Comment: As Terry pointed, you won't be able to do it with a single `oledb` connection. An option is to import the `Excel` sheet into the `Access` and then use a single connection